# Create snapshot in virsh for domain with two or more disks

Tags: backup, linux-kvm, snapshot, virsh

I would like to back up the disks of a VM following the [Live-disk-backup-with-active-blockcommit](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Live-disk-backup-with-active-blockcommit) procedure at Libvirt Wiki.

1. I create an external snapshot with

   ```
   virsh snapshot-create-as --domain vm_name snap_name \
       --diskspec vda,file=snapshot_folder/snap.qcow2 \
       --disk-only --atomic --quiesce
   ```
2. Copy the base disk to the remote location.
3. Commit the disk with

   ```
   virsh blockcommit vm_name vda --active --verbose --pivot
   ```
4. Delete the snapshot with

   ```
   virsh snapshot-delete vm_name --metadata snap_name
   ```

This procedure seems to work, but only with a VM with a single disk. If I try to create a snapshot for machines with two disks, the procedure fails. For instance: if a VM has two disks, `vba` and `vdb`,
and I try to run the exact same command as shown in step 1 above,
the command returns

```
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'transaction': Could not create file: Permission denied
```

I tried with two `--diskspec` parameters, one for `vda` and one for `vdb`, but the result is the same.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, which I tried to share with additional information about the symptom. But my contribution was deleted by the moderator. Anyway, I have since found the problem. The version of qemu-kvm that was included in the Ubuntu packages for 18.04 is 2.11 which is *really* old and apparently did not have the ability to handle multiple disks in this manner. I did a wipe and reload to 20.04 which includes qemu-kvm version 4.2. The symptom is no more.

- Non-working: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qemu-kvm
- Working: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qemu-kvm

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had a chance to try yet (considering that this is a delicate operation). You think it is possible to upgrade only qemu without reinstall the OS?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far is creating a `--diskspec` for every disk, but the disk to not be handled must contain the `snapshot=no`.

Example:

```
virsh snapshot-create-as --domain ${VM} 
--name "backup-${VM}" 
--atomic 
--disk-only 
--no-metadata 
--diskspec vda,file=${SNAP}/backup-snapshot-${VM} 
--diskspec vdb,snapshot=no
```

Note:

`${VM}` is the vm-name.

`${SNAP}` is the directory where snapshot has to be created.